# SQL Server 2008: copying the contents of all tables from one database into another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have two databases with THE SAME schema. I need to copy the contents of all the tables from one database into the other database. What is the best way to do this? There are about 200 tables. I have ssms.

Comment: SQL Examiner suite. Used it in a Database containing over 900   tables to great effect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the data in the 2nd database (you're not looking for a merge), you can back up your database, then restore it over the other one.

I can post screenshots to demonstrate how if you like.

~~~~~~~~Screenshots added~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Open management studio & connect, then go into backup database from Tasks menu:

[image]

Then click OK button to back up database (Note, picking a different back up directory such as C:\ may not be a bad idea so that it is not "in use" when trying to restore it later):

[image]

Select Restore for the 2nd database you wish to paste over:

[image]

Select the 1st database from the list, or browse to the file to backup from:

[image]

It may be neccessary to check this check box on the options tab when performing a restore over existing data:

[image]

Click OK and it should work.

Comment: i just want all the data frmo one db to be copied to the other one. i would LOVE some snapshots! thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the export wizard in SSMS. Right-click on the source database, select Tasks/Export data and follow the steps. A little tedious for 200 tables, but it's free.

Answer (score 2):

Without spending $, you could use the [SELECT ... INTO ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) syntax -- providing the table specified in the INTO clause does not exist already in the target database:

```
SELECT *
  INTO new_db.dbo.table
  FROM old_db.dbo.table
```

But that won't migrate constraints, triggers, jobs, logins, roles, etc.  If the databases are on different hosts, you can use a [Linked Server instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) to connect them and use four name notation to reference the remote instance.

As for dealing with ~200 tables, you'd need to use dynamic SQL to create the statement because you can't supply a table name as a variable in dynamic SQL.  The list of tables can come from either [SYS.TABLES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) or [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself Red-Gate [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) - best tool for the job, hands down.

**Update:** if you can't or don't want to spend any money, but instead want to spend a lot of your time, you can of course do something like this for each table:

```
INSERT INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.YourTable1(list of fields)
   SELECT (list of fields) FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.YourTable1
```

and then repeat this for the other 199 tables, too.

Comment: @marc: i just want to copy everything from one database into the other

Comment: yes - get SQL Data Compare for that job - it's the best tool around to do this.

Comment: @marc is there a free way to do this?

Comment: No - either you spend a lot of your time (is that worth nothing?), or you get a tool to help you

Comment: @marc u are definitely right, but i would need to tell my boss that he has to pay $400 to copy some tables

Comment: How many hours will you need to spend to manually copy 200 tables??? 10 table per hour = 20 hours..... how much do you earn per hour ?? Yes, it costs money - once, when you buy it. You'll **save** tons of your precious time over the months of using it .....

Comment: @marc it will take me maybe 30 min, thanks to you helping me getting all the tables names , i can just do what you suggest excel (create the 200 insert statements quickly and im done) i already have a list of the tables: use whd;
go
SELECT  [Name]      = o.name
    ,     [RowCount]  = SUM(p.row_count)

FROM    SYS.DM_DB_PARTITION_STATS p

INNER JOIN
        SYS.TABLES o
    ON p.[object_ID] = o.[object_id]

WHERE   index_id    <= 1 -- Heap or clustered index only

GROUP BY o.name

ORDER   BY 2 desc

Answer (score 1):

I use RedGate's Data compare it works really well comes in handy when trying to solve data issues.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/

Comment: i just want to copy everything from one database into the other