# SQL Server Copying tables from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-migration

I have two databases, one is called `Natalie_playground` and one is called `LiveDB`.
Since I want to practice insert, update things, I want to copy some of the tables from the `LiveDB` to `Natalie_playground`.

The tables I want to copy are called:
    `Customers, Computers, Cellphones, Prices`

What I tried to do is that (using SSMS) right click on a table but there is no Copy in there!

Comment: In both databases exists the same tables (with the same structure)? only you want pass only a data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008: copying the contents of all tables from one database into another database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028104/sql-server-2008-copying-the-contents-of-all-tables-from-one-database-into-anoth) and [How to copy one table from a database to another database/table in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/187770/62576), both of which are listed in the `Related` list to the right of your question. ===>>> Please do at least a basic search here before posting a new question to see if it has already been asked (and answered) before. Thanks.

Comment: @natalia, Ken have reason, for this question, normally the answers already exists. Thanks.

Comment: I already did that research, as a beginner I did not know what is that .. in the syntax of: How to copy one table from a database to another database/table in SQL Server. So this is why I asked and got a syntax at least I can understand.

Comment: take a look at David's answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that you have two databases, for example A and B:

- If target table not exists, the following script will create (I do not recommend this way):

  ```
  SELECT table_A.FIELD_1, table_A.FIELD_2,......, table_A.FIELD_N 
  INTO COPY_TABLE_HERE 
  FROM  A.dbo.table_from_A table_A
  ```
- If target table exists, then:

  ```
   INSERT INTO TABLE_TARGET 
   SELECT table_A.FIELD_1, table_A.FIELD_2,......, table_A.FIELD_N 
   FROM  A.dbo.table_from_A table_A
  ```

Note: if you want learn and practice this, you can use previous scripts, but if you want copy the complete structure and data from database to another, you should use, "Backup and restore Database" or, "Generate Script Database with data" and run this into another database.

Comment: Can you do this without selecting the field names explicitly?

Answer (score 9):

Right click on your database -> under **Tasks** choose **Generate scripts**, follow the wizard, choose your tables and check the check box that says **'script table data'** (or similar) generate it to an SQL script and execute it on your other DB.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try SQL Server Import/Export wizard. If target tables do not exist already they will be created when you run the wizard.

Check out MSDN for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Comment: Probably the simplest and least time consuming.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way from other blog. Hope this might be helpful.

```
Select * into DestinationDB.dbo.tableName from SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/664327/Copy-Table-Schema-and-Data-From-One-Database-to-An

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

If target table is exists :

```
SELECT SourceTableAlias.*
INTO TargetDB.dbo.TargetTable
FROM  SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable SourceTableAlias
```

And if target table is not exists :

```
 INSERT INTO TargetDB.dbo.TargetTable 
 SELECT SourceTableAlias.*
 FROM SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable SourceTableAlias
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
USE TargetDatabase
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable
WHERE (some condition)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to copy only the schema of tables, you can add a false condition to the end of mentioned queries.

ex.

```
SELECT table_A.FIELD_1, ..., table_A.FIELD_N 
INTO LiveDB.custom_table
FROM  Natalie_playground.dbo.custom_table table_A
WHERE 0 > 1
```