# Overwrite SQL table within same server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582957/sql-server-copying-tables-from-one-database-to-another) that could be the solution to my question, but I need some clarification.

I have two DBs on one server, the one DB is a backup. I have a broken table and want to replace the table values/records with the table from the backup DB. Can I use the method from the link above, or is it only if the destination table is empty that I can use the "INSERT INTO destination"?

My goal is to overwrite the table with the backup values.

Comment: INSERT INTO will only insert, you could look into the MERGE statement if you want to insert new row and update existing rows without delete.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal is to replace the entire table with the table from the backup database, you can `TRUNCATE` the target table and then reload from the backup table using `INSERT`...`SELECT`.

You will need to be mindful of foreign key constraints.  `TRUNCATE` is not allowed if FKs reference the table so you will need to use DELETE to empty the table instead.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I have to do, replace the entire table. I am not experienced in SQL, so this is relative new for me. How can i see if the table is dependent of FKs, and how to turn them off/delete before I do the Truncate, Insert, Select.

Comment: One method to identify referencing foreign key constraints is with "EXEC sp_help 'dbo.YourTargetTable';".  If FKs reference the table, just use `DELETE` instead of `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: My solution was to only copy the columns that was wrong in the original table, and not touch the ID column, so I just used 'UPDATE' and 'SELECT' and 'JOIN' where I joined my IDies.